# Use .pwsh instead of .ps1 extension for PowerShell Core scripts?

Tags: powershell, file-extension, powershell-core

I am using `PowerShell` and `PowerShell Core` in parallel.
Not all my scripts which I have wrote for the "big" PowerShell are working in PowerShell Core and vice versa.

To avoid chaos, I was thinking if I should use two file-extensions:

- `.ps1`: PowerShell
- `.pwsh`: PowerShell Core

In **Windows** the extension is more important then in **Unix** systems where the `shebang` (#!/bin/mytool) would help to solve the problem.

Is the usage of two extension "best practice" or there are better options?

**Additional**: I am not sure if a `.pwsh` script will be executed by PowerShell when I call a script from command line / terminal.

I found a similar question in Unix / Linux context.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182882/use-sh-or-bash-extension-for-bash-scripts

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add a line

```
#requires -PSEdition Core
```

at the beginning of your scripts for PowerShell Core, and a line

```
#requires -PSEdition Desktop
```

at the beginning of your scripts for regular PowerShell.

For scripts that run in both editions just omit the line.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires):

> **`-PSEdition <PSEdition-Name>`**
>
> Specifies a PowerShell edition that the script requires. Valid values are **Core** for PowerShell Core and **Desktop** for Windows PowerShell.

Do not use different extensions, as that will impact functionality. For instance, PowerShell will not dot-source scripts with an extension other than .ps1.

Comment: Thanks. It works :-). When the script is for both editions then just skip the line, isn't it? Also I will keep the extension .ps1

Comment: *"When the script is for both editions then just skip the line, isn't it?"* Correct.